# How do I center the Title and author name

Tags: templates

```
\documentclass[13pt,singlecolumn,twoside]{osajnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage [style=alphabetic]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\journal{jocn}

\begin{document}
   \title{Cause Related Marketing - Improving Consumer Purchase Intention through better Brand Image}

\author[1]{Aarti Kadyan}

\affil[1]{Assistant professor, University of Delhi}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: aarti.phdmp21@iift.edu} 

\begin{abstract}
   The purpose of this paper is to examine the relationship between corporate image and purchase intentions of the consumers related to cause marketing. A primary conceptualization was first developed from existing literature on cause related marketing and then validated through empirical research. A questionnaire was then developed on variables such as corporate image and consumer purchase intentions and data was collected from 65 consumers from Delhi and NCR. Further regression analysis was used to find the relationship between the two variables. It was found that consumer purchase intention is dependent on corporate image of the company supporting cause marketing. The study also investigated the relationship between key socio-demographic variables such as age, gender, income and professional status of the consumer and the purchase intention of the consumer. Independent sample t-test and One-way Anova test was performed on the data collected and was found that the above socio-demographic variables do not differ across purchase intentions of the consumer. The key implications of these findings for marketing managers developing cause related marketing strategies were that it is more important to focus on improving the brand and corporate image of the company through cause related marketing campaigns to improve consumer purchase intentions towards the company’s products. Also with a positive corporate image and good cause related campaigns socio demographic variables do not have much impact on the purchase intentions of the consumer.
Keywords: cause-related marketing; consumer behaviour; corporate image; purchase intentions; marketing strategy; marketing communication
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Abstract is in the center but not the title and author name. I have used a template in overleaf if I'm changing the document class to article I get too many errors due to the set up of the rest of the article. I just want to center my title and name.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Are you sure that `style=alphabetic` is an option that's recognized by `natbib`?

Comment: Sorry but your class file `osajnl` cannot be found and when I tried to copy the `cls` file it yields a bunch of problems. Maybe you can provide a link to those files and make the code really compilable. At least I cannot find `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have two choices: modify \maketitle, or simply format the title yourself.  In both cases you should look at the definition of \maketitle in osajnl.cls (or from wherever it is inherited).

Answer (score 0):

To center the title and the author:

**(1)** Add this code to your preamble:

```
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\raggedright}
{\centering}
{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\raggedright}
{\centering}
{}{}
```

**(2)** Save this file as `jocn.sty` in the legacy-styles subdirectory of the `osajnl` template (the file is missing from the template).

You can change the colors if you wish.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{legacy-styles/jocn}[2019/05/13 v1.0 Journal of Optical Communications and Networking color scheme]

% Set journal name for header
\newcommand*{\journalname}{}

% Set journal article types
\newcommand*{\journalshorttype}{Letter}
\newcommand*{\journallongtype}{}

% Set color for header, authors, table lines
% For long articles
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{100,125,51} % dark green
% For short articles
\definecolor{color2b}{RGB}{100,125,51} % also dark green

% Set bibliography style
\bibliographystyle{osajnl}

\endinput
```

**(3)** Use `\usepackage{natbib}`

[image: a]

This is the complete code

```
\documentclass[13pt,singlecolumn,twoside]{osajnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}% do not use style=alphabetic!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{caption}

%% ******************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\raggedright}
{\centering}
{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\raggedright}
{\centering}
{}{}
%% ********************

\journal{jocn}% Choose journal (ao,jocn,josaa,josab,ol,optica,pr) <<<<  but jocn is missing !!!

\begin{document}
    \title{Cause Related Marketing - Improving Consumer Purchase Intention through better Brand Image}
    
    \author[1]{Aarti Kadyan}
    
    \affil[1]{Assistant professor, University of Delhi}
    \affil[*]{Corresponding author: aarti.phdmp21@iift.edu} 
    
    \begin{abstract}
        The purpose of this paper is to examine the relationship between corporate image and purchase intentions of the consumers related to cause marketing. A primary conceptualization was first developed from existing literature on cause related marketing and then validated through empirical research. A questionnaire was then developed on variables such as corporate image and consumer purchase intentions and data was collected from 65 consumers from Delhi and NCR. Further regression analysis was used to find the relationship between the two variables. It was found that consumer purchase intention is dependent on corporate image of the company supporting cause marketing. The study also investigated the relationship between key socio-demographic variables such as age, gender, income and professional status of the consumer and the purchase intention of the consumer. Independent sample t-test and One-way Anova test was performed on the data collected and was found that the above socio-demographic variables do not differ across purchase intentions of the consumer. The key implications of these findings for marketing managers developing cause related marketing strategies were that it is more important to focus on improving the brand and corporate image of the company through cause related marketing campaigns to improve consumer purchase intentions towards the company’s products. Also with a positive corporate image and good cause related campaigns socio demographic variables do not have much impact on the purchase intentions of the consumer.
        Keywords: cause-related marketing; consumer behaviour; corporate image; purchase intentions; marketing strategy; marketing communication
    \end{abstract}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    See the OSA's \href{http://www.opticsinfobase.org/submit/style/}{Style Guide} and \href{http://www.opticsinfobase.org/submit/templates/}{Manuscript Templates} pages for more details. Please select the appropriate journal abbreviation in the document preamble.
    
    If you have a question while using this template on {Overleaf}, please use the help menu (``?'') on the top bar to search for help or ask us a question using our \href{https://www.overleaf.com/contact}{contact form}.
\end{document}
```

Template downloaded from [submission to OPG journals AO, JOCN, JOSA A, JOSA B, OL, Optica, and PRJ](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/length-check-latex-template-for-preparing-an-article-for-submission-to-osa-journals-ao-jocn-josa-a-josa-b-ol-optica-and-prj/gwgyrtrjkpcy)